# Show item as local task but hide if argument is not provided

Tags: routes

I have three tabs and third have wildcard in path. I added access callback for this menu item that checks if no argument then close access. The tab not shows afte that but ther is error "Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in _menu_translate()". So how correctly hhide this tab?

Access callback that I wrote:

```
/**
 * System log view access callback.
 */
function ebanq_custom_system_log_view_access($log_id) {
    return is_numeric($log_id) && user_access('access content');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by argument load function, but I don't think it is correct to do like this.

```
// Menu item change
//....
'system-log/%ebanq_custom_log_id/view' => array(
//....

/**
 * Implements hook_load().
 */
function ebanq_custom_log_id_load($arg) {
    if (!is_numeric($arg)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return $arg;
}
```